# Python edit modify dict values by reference

Tags: python, pointers, dictionary, reference

I'm building an application with Python 3 and PyQt5 where I have to generate a TreeView from any dict. Treeview will have data items containing rows which are formed from dict's value and key pairs. Values should be editable in the UI. Now, it was easy enough to generate items from dict with this code:

```
 def createTreeFromDict(self, data, parent, top=False):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                node = TreeItem([key, ""], parent)
                parent.appendChild(node)
                self.createTreeFromDict(value, node)

            elif isinstance(value, list):
                node = TreeItem([key, ""], parent)
                parent.appendChild(node)
                self.createTreeFromDict(value, node)

            else:
                print(key)
                print(value)
                node = TreeItem([key, value], parent)
                parent.appendChild(node)


    if isinstance(data, list):
        for index, value in enumerate(data):
            if isinstance(value, dict):

                node = TreeItem([index+1, ""], parent)
                parent.appendChild(node)
                self.createTreeFromDict(value, node)

            elif isinstance(value, list):
                node = TreeItem([index+1, ""], parent)
                parent.appendChild(node)
                self.createTreeFromDict(value, node)

            else:
                node = TreeItem(["juttu", value], parent)
                parent.appendChild(node)

    if top:
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
```

However, I'm thinking how I should bind it to the original multidimensional dict so that when user edits one item's value, it changes the value in the original dict. The problem is that the dict can contain child dicts and lists so I can't just store key to the Item along with reference to the original dict.

I think I could do a recursive search through the original dict to find the correct dict key-value pair but first I'd like to know if following would be possible:

When I create the item in code on top, you can see how I pass the new TreeItem the key and value: `node = TreeItem([key, value], parent)`

Would it be possible to pass also a reference/pointer to the this specific key-value pair in the original dict to the TreeItem? So that if I edit the value of the reference, it will update the value in the original dict? Or in other terms how I could pass mydict["mykey"] as a a variable which references to the original object?

Comment: what are the values? If the value is a `mutable` then you don't have to do anything special - i.e. wrap your value in an object with set() get() and just modify the ref you've got

Comment: They are mostly integers and strings. I'm now considering some thin wrapper to pass them around like you said

Comment: Why can't you just rebuild your nested data structure from the values stored in the UI once they hit "Submit" (or equivalent)? It's a Good Idea to avoid modifying the original object, as that makes it hard to implement undo functionality, and users will _hate_ you if you don't give them some degree of undo-ability.

Comment: Good point. I didn't consider that possibility.